# Dropping packets from IPTables

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iptables

I am wondering how do I set a rule in my IPTables to drop packets from a specific IP address at a given probability of dropping.

Eg. for dropping any random packet from any IP, I would use the command:

```
# for randomly dropping 10% of incoming packets:
iptables -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j DROP
```

However, I want to drop a specific IP at a given probability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you read [this tutorial here](http://code.nomad-labs.com/2010/03/11/simulating-dropped-packets-aka-crappy-internets-with-iptables/). Have you tried this. Assuming your IP address is `123.456.78.90`:

```
iptables -s 123.456.78.90/32 -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j DROP
```

Or perhaps:

```
iptables -s 123.456.78.90/32 -p tcp -m tcp -A INPUT -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.1 -j DROP
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, what is the FORWARD parameter for in the IPTables?